# Probability of event M

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I am solving the Strategic Practice and Homework Ex#2 of the course [Stat 110](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home) by Harvard University (I am not a student there, I am practicing Probability). I have a conceptual doubt in one of the questions. Here's the question as it is:

> ([Q4, Practice 2](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf)) A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there
>   is equal evidence against both of them. In further investigation at
>   the crime scene, it is found that the guilty party had a blood type
>   found in 10% of the population. Suspect A does match this blood type,
>   whereas the blood type of Suspect B is unknown.

In the solution to this question we have:

> Let M be the event that A’s blood type matches the guilty party’s and
>   for brevity, write A for “A is guilty” and B for “B is guilty”

As per the solution we have $P(\frac{M}{A})=1$ and my doubt is that as we already know that the blood group of A matches with the particular blood type discussed in the question, so shouldn't $P(M)=1$ because we already know that A has this particular blood group.
I am not getting error with this reasoning and it has to be wrong because 
$P(M)≠P(\frac{M}{A})$.

### Edit:

It's been pointed out in one of the comments that here $P(M) = P(\frac{M}{A})$ but I am not quite sure if that is right because, part of the [solution](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf) of this question is the following image:
[Part of the solution to calculate P(A|M)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYlRp.png)
Here we can see that the $P(\frac{A}{M}) = \frac{10}{11}$ but if we assume that $P(\frac{M}{A}) = P(M)$ then it would be $\frac{1}{2}$ because $P(\frac{A}{M}) = P(\frac{M}{A})*\frac{P(A)}{P(M)} = P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ which doesn't look right.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Plese use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to make your formulas more readable.

Comment: In this case, $P(M) = P(M|A)$

Comment: Hi, I am not quite sure if that is right here. I have edited my question to show why it doesn't look right to me. Please check it out.

Comment: Is $P(\frac{A}{M})$ supposed to be $P(A|M)$?

Comment: Both are same; $P(\frac{A}{M})$ is same as $P(A|M)$